# Clicking sound in engine, very strange evolution

Tags: engine, noise, oil, ignition, misfire

I have come here in hopes to get some help regarding my impala. It is a 2006 Chevy Impala with a V6 engine,

I was out of town for 2 weeks and when I got home I got in my impala and stated her up. it was a bit of a colder day, and I immediately noticed a strange squeaking sound, I made a video of the initial sound here:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=mhZpt28WFI8

I continued to let the car warm up and after 5 minutes of being warm the squeaking went away and turned to a clicking type sound. I put in drive to take it around the block and the engine lost power when trying to leave a stop sign. Immediately I got a flashing check engine light. code p0300 ( multiple cylinder misfire).

I turned the engine off and waited a while and went to turn it back on, still hear clicking but no more check engine light. I can note the sound is consistent and does not get better or worse based on being warmed up or not and it matches the RPMs of the engine.

It sounds to be coming from the top of the engine in the middle. I’m not a mechanic so I can’t be sure. I tried to change the oil and filter, afterward I drove it around for 10 minutes and the tapping sound went away and returned to a squeak for 10 seconds and immediately came back. No codes anymore, no lights on,nothing.

I have uploaded a video of the clicking noise it is making, if someone would be kind enough to take a listen and let me know what they think it may be, it would be greatly appreciated.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=kJzl8XNBebY

Side note: The car has a small oil leak appearing to come from around the oil filter, which is tight and not coming from that. Smells like it’s burning oil as well but hard to tell as there is a small leak, 1 drip every few seconds. I don’t have a lot of history of the car as I bought it used.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: it sounds as though you have a cracked exhaust manifold.

Comment: Hi Paul, I don’t think that sounds the same as the sound that I am experiencing here. Especially considering it started as a squeak. From what I heard when I looked at videos of the cracked exhaust, it sounded much more subtle then the sound I have

Comment: Don't be so certain. Your description and the sounds which I'm hearing very much sound like one. If the manifold is cracked and is puffing exhaust onto the thin metal heat shield, it would sound *exactly* like what I'm hearing.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely take a look at it then. Really appreciate your response and input here. I’ll get under the car tomorrow and look to see if I can find anything. Any good way to tell? Would it be big or obvious or would I need some sort of tool to test?

Comment: It will probably be very hard to see/locate with the tins in the way. You may be able to spot it if you were to use an infrared device, as the heat shield would be very much hotter where the exhaust leak is at. Other than that, dismantlement may not be out of the question.